# Symfony 2 form $_POST data escaped - FIXED

Tags: php, html, symfony, post, change-password

I have a Symfony 2 form which POST data to change password of users. However during testing I found out some characters entered in password field get escaped when it hits validator.

Ex:

User enters a password like `RzB&EUgbrhqJRt$Y2`

In validator this value becomes `RzB&amp;EUgbrhqJRt$Y2`

Notice that `&` has escaped to `&amp;`

This simply breaks some of my validation rules. I could not find why and how to disable this escaping thing. Fairly new to Symfony and looking for some help regarding this matter.

Build form code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('currentPassword', PasswordType::class, [
            'constraints' => new UserPassword(['groups' => [UserProfile::VALIDATION_PASSWORD], 'message' => 'Current password is invalid.']),
            'mapped' => false,
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Current Login Password',
                'required' => 'true',
                'data-parsley-required-message' => 'Please enter your current login password',
                'autocomplete' => 'disabled'
            ]
        ]);

        $builder->add(self::FORM_NEW_PASSWORD, RepeatedType::class, [
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'mapped' => false,
            'constraints' => [
                new NewPassword(['groups' => [UserProfile::VALIDATION_PASSWORD]])
            ],
            'first_options' => [
                'attr' => [
                    'id' => 'change_password_newPassword_first',
                    'maxlength' => 40,
                    'minlength' => 10,
                    'data-parsley-password' => '',
                    'placeholder' => 'New Password',
                    'data-parsley-required-message' => 'Please enter your new password',
                    'autocomplete' => 'disabled'
                ]
            ],
            'second_options' => [
                'attr' => [
                    'data-parsley-equalto' => '#change_password_newPassword_first',
                    'placeholder' => 'Confirm New Password',
                    'data-parsley-required-message' => 'Please re-enter your new password',
                    'autocomplete' => 'disabled'
                ]
            ]
        ]);

        $builder->add('change', SubmitType::class, [
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'btn-full-width',
                'data-parsley-validate' => 1,
                'disabled' => 'disabled'
            ]
        ]);

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, [$this, 'onPostSubmit']);
    }
```

Form validation constraint:

```
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint) 
        {
            //$value HERE IS ESCAPED
            $zxcvbn = new Zxcvbn();
            $strength = $zxcvbn->passwordStrength($value);

            $pp = new PwnedPasswords();
            if (!preg_match(NewPassword::REGEX, $value)) {
                // Match password pattern
                $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->messagePasswordNotValid)
                    ->setParameter('{{ value }}', $this->formatValue($value))
                    ->addViolation();
            } else if ($strength["score"] < 3) {
                // Calculate password strength
                $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->messagePasswordNotStrong)
                    ->setParameter('{{ value }}', $this->formatValue($value))
                    ->addViolation();
            } else if ($pp->isInsecure($value)) {
                // Check to see if the password is breached
                $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->messagePasswordBreached)
                    ->setParameter('{{ value }}', $this->formatValue($value))
                    ->addViolation();
            }
        }
```

**FIXED:**

The issue caused by html_purifier_extension in forms config. Disabling that fixed the issue.
Although the `extended_type: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType` , not sure why it effected password field as well. Need to investigate more.

Comment: Can you show the code ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI Which part of the code?

Comment: the code that handle the form

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI Code added.

Comment: whant inside $value in your constraint ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI It's the value that user enters as new password (first_options). So user enters RzB&EUgbrhqJRt$Y2 into the password field and when it comes to the constraint($value), it becomes RzB&amp;EUgbrhqJRt$Y2

Comment: what if you try htmlspecialchars_decode($value); ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI What is someone will enter &amp; as a part of the password? Converting that will be an issue again.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the cause: Do not `htmlspecialchars()` data that you are not echoing. This may be the cause. `htmlspecialchars()` is used for sanitizing data that you will print to a HTML parser.

Comment: I'm not using htmlspecialchars() or anything like that in code. This is just plain sumfony form using form builder.

Answer (score 0):

I think Mohammed was right with suggesting to use `htmlspecialchars_decode($value);`.

And when someone uses `&amp;` in their password, e.g.

```
Zdv5&amp;rwv)
```

, the `$value` that the validator will receive will have the `&` sign in the `&amp;` encoded to `&amp;`, making it `&amp;amp;`, so the whole password will end up being

```
Zdv5&amp;amp;rwv)
```

Check [here](https://3v4l.org/TQHDc) for code example.

Comment: but why would the value returned by the form ever be html encoded? OP should fix this at the client end.

Comment: Not sure why it's being encoded. I've noticed that the form has a post submit event listener, could you also paste the code if it?

Comment: It was caused by html_purifier_extension.